# Oozie taking longer to run compared to Hive CLI

Tags: hive, hiveql, oozie

There are 2 problems I'm currently encountering:-

- Oozie job hive SQL is taking 2 hours to complete whereas running the same SQL in Hive/Beeline CLI, it took around 6 to 7 minutes.
- The same SQL ran in Oozie and Hive/Beeline CLI but both seems to be using different memory allocation even though the same hive-site.xml was used in both execution.

I get an error when running in Oozie but no error when running in CLI with the same SQL.  Somehow the hybridhashtablecontainer memory allocation was different.

From the logs below, when running in Oozie, the memory allocated was 5000000, but when I ran in Hive/Beeline CLI, the allocation was 10000000 and the partitioning allocation was successful if memory is higher

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Logs

```
|tez.HashTableLoader|: Memory manager allocates 5000000 bytes for the loading hashtable.
|persistence.HashMapWrapper|: Key count from statistics is 1; setting map size to 2
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Available memory is not enough to create a HybridHashTableContainer!
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Total available memory: 5000000
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Estimated small table size: 105
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Number of hash partitions to be created: 16
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Total available memory is: 5000000
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Write buffer size: 524288
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Using a bloom-1 filter 2 keys of size 8 bytes
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Each new partition will require memory: 65636
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 0 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 65644
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 1 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 131280
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 2 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 196916
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 3 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 262552
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 4 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 328188
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 5 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 393824
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 6 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 459460
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 7 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 525096
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 8 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 590732
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 9 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 656368
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 10 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 722004
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 11 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 787640
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 12 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 853276
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 13 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 918912
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 14 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 984548
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Hash partition 15 is created in memory. Total memory usage so far: 1050184
 |persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: There is not enough memory to allocate 16 hash partitions.
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Number of partitions created: 16
|persistence.HybridHashTableContainer|: Number of partitions spilled directly to disk on creation: 0
```

### hive-site.xml

```
 ....
 <property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>tez</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
   <value>maprfs:///apps/tez/tez-0.8,maprfs:///apps/tez/tez-0.8/lib</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>hive.tez.container.size</name>
   <value>6144</value>
 </property>
 ...
```

Comment: Beeline is a **thin** client using HiveServer2 to run queries, and that service may use specific settings. The Oozie equivalent would be a `hive2` action (does not require hive-site.xml), not the legacy `hive` action using fat client libraries and hive-site.xml

Comment: Unfortunately our oozie jobs are running from a legacy implementation, it is still running through hive cli instead of hive2 (jdbc).  Even I ran the SQL via Hive legacy CLI which is direct to metastore instead of Hiveserver2 jdbc, I still manage to complete the SQL query at less than 7mins.   There must be some setting that Oozie initiate Hive CLI very differently than running it off from Hive CLI.  I just couldn't figure out what is the differences.

Comment: Back in the day, I chose to develop a tiny Java app to open a JDBC connection to HS2 and run whatever commands were passed as arguments. With Kerberos I had to also `<file>` a keytab and a JAAS conf file, but it worked quite well as a Java action...

Comment: BTW did you try to dump the actual props values used by your Hive session, with a series of `SET prop.a  ;  SET prop.b  ;  ` etc ?

Comment: I will try dumping the properties in both execution and see what's the differences.  By the way, managed to resolve the 2nd item regarding to hash map join memory issue.  Just need to tweak  `hive.auto.convert.join.nonconditionaltask.size` higher.  I might also try changing one of our Oozie workflow to use `hive2` action to see if there is any differences.  Will update back here on the result shortly

Comment: Hey Sam, I have changed one of our workflow to use `hive2` action and it does work as fast as hive CLI.  I will not waste the time to find out why `hive` works differently.  I will change the workflow to use `hive2` going forward.  Thanks for your earlier comment that enlighten me to try out `hive2`.